Could Information Density be the Universal Framework We’re Missing in Physics?
I’ve been developing a theoretical framework suggesting that information density might be a fundamental principle underlying everything from quantum mechanics to consciousness. Here’s the core idea:
Information density could determine how systems behave, evolve, and transform across all scales of reality. Imagine it as a “Goldilocks zone” for complexity—where systems naturally seek states with optimal information density.
Why This Matters:
•   It might explain why some systems evolve toward complexity while others stay simple.
•   It could bridge the gap between quantum mechanics and macro-scale physics.
•   It offers a new perspective on the emergence of consciousness.
•   It could provide insight into phase transitions across diverse systems.
Examples in Nature:
1.  DNA: A highly optimized information storage system with specific density limits.
2.  Stars: Manage information density through processes like radiation.
3.  Brain: Consciousness might emerge at certain information density thresholds.
4.  Evolution: Species development as a process of optimizing information density.
The Big Question:
Could this framework help unify our understanding of physical laws, biological evolution, and consciousness?
Looking for thoughts, critiques, and discussion:
What are the potential flaws in this theory? Where might it apply best? I’m not claiming this is a proven idea—just a theoretical framework I’m exploring and would love your feedback on.

Please note: Unfortunately, this block is not intended to put to discussion one's personal philosophical ideas and theory. See also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour

Short answer: no. Longer answer https://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/wp-content/ItFromQubit.pdf

What are the potential flaws in this theory? What testable predictions does this make? What pressing issues in physics does this propose to solve? We can already explain DNA and the like with organic chemistry, stellar evolution with astrophysics, etc. —these are not problems in physics at this time.

This sounds very similar to the Free energy principle. Free energy is a concept from thermodynamics and just like entropy (think Shannon entropy) it can also be applied to information.

The "free energy principle" is a theoretical framework in neuroscience that suggests living organisms, including the brain, actively try to minimize "free energy" - essentially a measure of uncertainty or surprise - by constantly updating internal models of their environment based on sensory input, leading to actions that best predict and maintain a stable state within their surroundings; it aims to unify perception, action, and learning within a single principle by optimizing predictions and minimizing discrepancies between internal models and external reality.

I think the idea is that the free energy principle scales and is also applicable to very different systems, including entire brains.
I find this super interesting and I think it is very promising. There is already some amazing research, my favourite being how human brain cells in a dish learnt to play Pong.  The leading figure in this field seems to be Karl Friston, but unfortunately, I think he's not the best science communicator.

One major hurdle is saying what information is. Can it really be a fundamental quantity?
Information theory associates information with such quantities as the negative log probability of an observation, or the entropy of a probability distribution.
But probability is subjective. It describes what a particular agent doesn't know. A single message could impart more information to one agent than another, because the second agent already expected that message and the first agent did not. The amount of information (in the information-theoretic sense) contained in a strand of DNA could be quite low - if the person examining the DNA strand already knows what genes it contains.
Note that information already does play a major role in physics. Information entropy is essentially the same as thermodynamic entropy. Believe it or not, thermodynamic entropy also has a subjective nature; if agent A knows more about a system than agent B, the system actually has lower entropy for agent A, and agent A can potentially extract more useful work from the system than agent B can. These effects are typically quite small, because the amount it is possible for a human or even a supercomputer to know about a box of gas molecules is almost negligible in comparison to the entropy of the box.

It's a good idea, and it solves problems in physics. But it's not a new idea, and it doesn't solve the problems you're trying to solve.
Information science is a well-integrated part of physics already - in fact, its near-modern form predates quantum mechanics and relativistic mechanics, the other two pillars of modern physics, by a few decades. It does contribute to effective theories and models for bridging the gap between QM and relativity. The principles of statistical mechanics, although originally applied to physics in the context of classical gases, are essentially mathematical, not physical, and are broadly applicable to systems radically unlike classical gases. See for example arXiv:2003.02860.
If we ever obtain a theory of everything it will comport with and be informed by information science, just as classical mechanics did in the 19th century and quantum mechanics and relativistic mechanics did in the 20th century and present. But information science is unlikely to constitute any physical theory on its own. If it can, it has eluded over a hundred years of experts with the relevant knowledge, strong incentives to figure it out, and no significant disincentives against publication... so the chances that a layman can make advances in the field are not very good.
